# separately running a .bat file and .sh file depending in the Operating system

Tags: java

I want to be able to run a .sh on a mac os and a .bat file from a windows system using the same java application. 
Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an in-built api for finding the OS... in Java.

`System.getProperty("os.name");`.

You can then write a `case` or `if else`. Like...

```
private String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

if (os.contains("windows"){
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your batch file");
  p.waitFor();
} else if (os.contains("mac"){
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your sh file or dmg");
  p.waitFor();
} else {
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your .sh file");
  p.waitFor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Reff http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getproperties.htm
 */

import java.lang.String;

public class Main {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toString();
      System.out.println("OS: " + os );

      if("Windows 8".equals(os)) {
        System.out.println("Windows 8");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Others");
      }
    }
}
```